# Power BI - Pull data based of condition

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I want to know how I can pull certain data by applying a condition within PowerQuery. The condition is pulling current day data (6/4) if there is the same name within the past 5 days. The raw data is provided below.

[image: table 1]

So it would return the following:

```
6/4/2020 - Apple
6/4/2020 - Bear
6/3/2020 - Apple
6/2/2020 - Apple
6/2/2020 - Bear
5/31/2020 - Bear
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the current day by defining

```
MaxDate = List.Max(#"Previous Step"[Date])
```

then you can find the Names from that day by filtering

```
MaxDateNames = Table.SelectRows(#"Previous Step", each [Date] = MaxDate)[Name]
```

and you have enough to write a combined condition:

```
FilteredTable = Table.SelectRows(#"Previous Step",
     each [Date] > Date.AddDays(MaxDate, -5) and List.Contains(MaxDateNames, [Name]))
```

---

The whole query then looks like this:

```
let
    Source = <Your Data Source>,
    #"Previous Step" = <Steps applied to Source>,
    MaxDate = List.Max(#"Previous Step"[Date]),
    MaxDateNames = Table.SelectRows(#"Previous Step", each [Date] = MaxDate)[Name],
    FilteredTable = Table.SelectRows(#"Previous Step", each [Date] > Date.AddDays(MaxDate, -5) and List.Contains(MaxDateNames, [Name]))
in
    FilteredTable
```

Comment: Is it possible that if a name doesn't appear more than once, can we do it where it doesn't show the name on the table?

Comment: Probably. I'm not quite sure what you're asking but it sounds like a separate question.

Comment: I used this logic on another data set, and now it's showing a name on the current day but the same name doesn't exist within the past 5 days. How do I get the data not to show if it occurs only once.